# iPhone custom control animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, objective-c-blocks

I have a custom control that I'd like to implement "flick" style scrolling like ListViews have.  As its a continuously updating control displaying large volumes of data I calculate what is rendered when i need to render it.

I have implemented pinch-to-zoom and panning on the control.  Now however I'd like to allow the user to perform a pan using the flick gesture.  The only problem is I'm not sure how best to do this smoothly.  I need some way of setting something up like a UIAnimation block from which I can step the animation (with deceleration) along even when the control is not receiving continuous updates (and hence not changing).

I hope I've explained that adequately, if not feel free to ask questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually handled this by performing the updates in my render loop.  It works reasonably nicely.  Probably not quite the right acceleration for what the iPhone usually uses but it seems fine and much nicer than without it.